# Does each assignment of values to an output NetCDF variable result in a rewrite of the entire dataset?

Tags: python, numpy, netcdf

I am writing the results of a calculation to NetCDF variables at each iteration of a compute loop because I can't keep all the result data in memory before doing a single write to the variable.  My assumption was that each write to the NetCDF variable would only write the slice of data I'm writing and hence each write would be quick, however each write appears to be taking quite a while and my fear is that the entire NetCDF file is being rewritten at each variable assignment statement, rather than just the slice of data being assigned, resulting in quite an unnecessary I/O overhead.

The slices of result data are written into the output NetCDF variables like so:

```
outputSpi01MonthVariable[totalNumberOfOutputMonths, lat:lat + 1:1, len(lonDimension)] = spiScale01  # a numpy array with compatible shape assigned to the variable at specified indices
```

Is there a better way of assigning values to the output NetCDF variable which doesn't result in so much I/O overhead?  BTW I have set the fill to off for the output variables but this appears to have no effect.

Answer (score 3):

I use  [NetCDF4-Python](http://code.google.com/p/netcdf4-python/) for reading/writing NetCDF, and no, the whole file is not written when you write a variable, or chunk of a variable.  Here's a full example:
http://nbviewer.ipython.org/5764942

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the orientation of the variable makes a big difference when writing to output variable.  It seems that the fastest changing dimension of the data (time in my case, lat/lon are fixed at each write to the variable) should be the inner-most dimension of both the array being written and the variable itself.  In my case here I converted my output NetCDF variable's dimensions to (lat, lon, time) and at each iteration of my computation I write the array, which has shape == (1, 1, number_of_timesteps), and now the write to NetCDF is about twenty times as fast:

```
Original with variable dimensions: [time, lat, lon]

Total time:              0:22:35.852000
Total fill time:         0:00:00.254000
Total SPI compute time:  0:00:53.865000
Total copy time:         0:00:00.099000
Total NetCDF write time: 0:19:15.749000


New code with variable dimensions: [lat, lon, time]

Total time:              0:03:12.249000
Total fill time:         0:00:00.248000
Total SPI compute time:  0:00:53.843000
Total copy time:         0:00:00.083000
Total NetCDF write time: 0:00:46.250000
```